# Composer conflicts when installing orm-fixtures in Symfony 4/5

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I have a problem when I try to install `orm-fixtures` in Symfony **5.1**:

```sh
$ composer require orm-fixtures --dev
Using version ^3.3 for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - doctrine/common 2.2.1 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.2 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.3 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.3.0 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/co
mmon 2.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.1|remove doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|in
stall doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.1|don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2
.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Installation request for doctrine/cache (locked at 1.10.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.1|remove doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|in
stall doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.1|don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2
.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ^3.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.3.0, 3.3.1].
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.
3.0
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.0 requires doctrine/data-fixtures ^1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/data-fixtures[1.3.3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, v1.3
.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.3.3 requires doctrine/common ~2.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2
.3, 2.3.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1
, v2.9.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.4.0 requires doctrine/common ^2.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.11.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.4.1 requires doctrine/common ^2.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.11.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.4.2 requires doctrine/common ^2.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.11.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.4.3 requires doctrine/common ^2.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.11.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures v1.3.0 requires doctrine/common ~2.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.
2.3, 2.3.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.
1, v2.9.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures v1.3.1 requires doctrine/common ~2.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.
2.3, 2.3.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.
1, v2.9.0].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures v1.3.2 requires doctrine/common ~2.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.
2.3, 2.3.0, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.
1, v2.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.12.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.11.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.2.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.10.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.9.0, 3.0.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/common (locked at 3.0.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[3.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is the error that I got.

I know that problem coming from the versions of my libraries but I don't know how to fix it I started Symfony just today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Confirmed that as of 01 Sep 2020, the issue has been resolved.  Fixtures now load cleanly without any tweaks.  Those of you who used this procedure will probably want to remove the doctrine lines from the conflicts section and do another composer update just to get back in sync.

To reproduce the problem, start with a fresh 5.1 project and attempt to install the fixtures bundle:

```
symfony new --full new_project
cd new_project
composer require --dev orm-fixtures
```

And you get the big long error message.  This is something the powers that be are working on.  It's actually a bit strange that this sort of issue managed to slip though the various testing processes.  Very rare.

However you can work around it by doing a bit of doctrine downgrading.  Add these doctrine lines to composer.json:

```
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*",
        "doctrine/common": ">= 3.0",
        "doctrine/persistence": "<1.3"
    },
```

Then, the secret ingredient, you should clear the composer cache and do a composer update to actually downgrade doctrine:

```
composer clear-cache
composer update
composer require --dev orm-fixtures
```

And it should be working.

But again, this will hopefully all be fixed in the very near future.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the error message: the latest version of `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle` requires `doctrine/data-fixtures`. This package is not yet compatible with `doctrine/common` v3, but this version is currently installed on your system.

However you've installed `doctrine/common`, you need to downgrade it. If you need help doing so, please edit your question to contain your `composer.json`

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix in the making: https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/349/files

In the meantime you can install it by adding

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/fruitwasp/data-fixtures"
    }
],
```

to your `composer.json` and then running

```
composer require doctrine/data-fixtures:"dev-doctrinecommon as 1.4.3" --dev
composer require orm-fixtures --dev
```

Comment: I released the fix this morning